# Error with webpack using css-loader and text-extract-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I am using `webpack@2.2.0-rc.3` and `extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-beta.4` and I have the following webpack config:

```js
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './source/app.js',
    vendor: './source/vendor.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.tmp/dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css/,
      use:[ ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        loader: ["css-loader"],
      })],
    }],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[chunkhash].css",
      allChunks: true,
    })
  ]
};
```

In the `vendor.js` file I have this code:

```js
require("./asdf.css")
```

And in the `asdf.css` code I simply have

```css
body {
    background: yellow;
}
```

That's a pretty simple setting, yet I get this error when running webpack:

```
ERROR in ./source/asdf.css
Module build failed: ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: /home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/source/asdf.css Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| body {
|     background: yellow;
| }
    at /home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:210:34
    at /home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:164:10
    at /home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:365:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:206:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:197:4)
    at Storage.finished (/home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:15)
    at /home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:69:9
    at /home/vagrant/dorellang.github.io/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
 @ ./source/vendor.js 2:0-21
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading the css file, that's why you get the error. Try to replace rules this into your `webpack.congif.js` like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...  ...  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'ur path here')
    },
    { 
      test: /\.css$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'ur path here'),
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
    }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though "use" is supposed to replace (and be identical to) "loader" in Webpack 2.2.0, this does not appear to be the case.

It doesn't seem that you can use "use" yet with ExtractTextPlugin. Additionally, it doesn't seem that you can use an array value for "loader" (in place of "use").

If you replace this bit of code:

```
use:[ ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    loader: ["css-loader"],
})],
```

With this:

```
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    loader: ["css-loader"],
}),
```

..it should work. (That replacement worked for my similar broken test-case.)

It looks like the main related issue is https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/265